# If there is an algorithm A can calculate the modular square root of input n, How to use it to get prime factors?

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

> Suppose you are given an algorithm $A$ which takes $y \in \{0, 1, \ldots , N − 1\}$ as input, and outputs $x \in \{0,1,\ldots,N − 1\}$ such that $x^2 \equiv y \pmod{N}$. Design an efficient, randomized procedure that uses $A$ to get prime factors.

This is a homework problem for the graduate algorithm course.

It's similar to this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/square-roots-prime-factorization). The difference is that we don't have a specific number `51733469`. My idea is that we can randomly pick a number $a$ between $[1,n-1]$, use $A$ to calculate it's modular square root and do exactly like the [solution](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20011/74537) here? Or the randomly-picked number $a$ should satisfy any sort of condition?

Comment: This is rather do a research question. See [factor base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_base).

Comment: Hint: the problem with your idea of picking a random $a\in\{0,1,\ldots,N−1\}$ and submitting it to the algorithm is that you end up with a single $x\in\{0,1,\ldots,N−1\}$ with $x^2\equiv a\pmod n$. You want to have another. Asking again to the algorithm is of no help, for it can return the same $x$. You want to come up with that (hopefully) other $\tilde x$ with $\tilde x^2\equiv a\pmod n$ by yourself. Be lazy, and let the algorithm do the hard work.

Comment: @fgrieu I suppose  ^2 ≡  (mod ) should return multiple results (x1, x2, x3, x4), instead of a single one.

Comment: @CarenLai: the equation $x^2\equiv a\pmod n$ (written as `$x^2\equiv a\pmod n$`BTW) does not _return_ anything. It _has_ solutions. The algorithm $A$ returns an $x$ with $x^2\equiv a\pmod n$ when given $a$. But assume the worse: that $A$ will always return the same result for a given input, even if there are several possible solutions. Hint: decide $a$ in a way such that you know a solution before the algorithm gives one, and notice that the algorithm can't read your mind.

Comment: @fgrieu Yeah, That's true. What I forgot to mention is that I would do the algorithm $A$ multiple times, until I found the "correct" factors. The "correct" here means that the result of both `gcd(f1 - f2, n)` and `gcd(f1 + f2, n)` are prime numbers.

Comment: @Caren Lai:You seam determined to start by picking a random $a\in\{0,1,\ldots,N−1\}$, and that's fine. But submitting _it_ to $A$ multiple times won't do, for $A$ will (or at least, can) always result to the same output.

Comment: @fgrieu Let's make it clear. Actually I am not familiar with modular arithmetic and cryptography. So there may be some assumptions I don't know when we discuss the problem. Please point them out if you find it. There are a couple of  questions here:
1. How many solutions are there for equation $x^2\equiv a\pmod n$?
You said one, I thought it should be at least 4. (This should be one of my mistakes, I am not sure). 
2. Why the algorithm $A$ would always return the same output? 
The probability should be really small according to my standing of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many solutions are there for equation $x^2\equiv y\pmod N$?

That problem is easier when $N$ is odd and $\gcd(y,N)=1$ (notice that when either does not hold, we have a factor of $N$): there are either $0$ or $2^k$ solutions, where $k$ is the number of distinct primes $p_i$ dividing $N$. Proof starts with $N$ prime (see [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)), then a power of a prime, then the product of powers of distinct primes (using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)).

> Why the algorithm $A$ would always return the same output?

The proof thought to answer the question should work including when the algorithm $A$ always return the same output $x$ for input $(y,N)$, because nothing in the question's assumption "Suppose.." says that $A$ will return all solutions, or would eventually return all solutions when invoked repeatedly. Many algorithms are deterministic, that is always perform the same operations for a given input, including producing the same result. Actually, in cryptography, we often implicitly restrict to such deterministic algorithms, considering that a random behavior must come from an explicit extra random input.

Hint: you want to have two solutions: one you know beforehand, and one that the algorithm will give you. The algorithm can't read your mind, thus there's a chance that it will return another solution, and perhaps that will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps. I'll try to understand.